# how to call set of procedures in same time without using jobs and chain

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package inside package and I have 15 procedures is there but I will run 5 procedures same time,

example: proc1 call---12:22:55 
         proc2 call---12:22:55 
         proc3 call---12:22:55 
         proc4 call---12:22:55

I know that by using chains and jobs it's possible.

Without jobs and chains through front end 1 hit 4 procedures will run at the same time.

I want to start these four procs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [dbms_job](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#ARPLS66558)

Just create one `master procedure` which will call all the `child procedures` parallelly as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MASTER_PROC AS

BEGIN

DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(L_JOB, 'PROC1;');
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(L_JOB, 'PROC2;');
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(L_JOB, 'PROC3;');
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(L_JOB, 'PROC4;');

END MASTER_PROC;
/
```

Please make sure that [job_queue_processes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/initparams090.htm) is set to more than four as this parameter decides the maximum number of processes that can be created for the execution of jobs.

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks for your replay i know alreday thise process with out job any chance to call procs same time

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Here, We are not creating any JOBs but taking advantage of DBMS_JOBS